# Removing file extension and special characters

Tags: javascript

Hi what i am trying to remove file extension and special chracters but my problem is slight difficult thats my existing code

```
<script>
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
pathname = pathname.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,' ');
window.location="http://mimuz.com/search.php?keywords="+pathname;

</script>
```

In path name there are three portions forexample

```
/videos-of-stars-and-stellites-etc_fe5eb9bf1.html
```

to best explain url

**videos-of-stars-and-stellites-etc = Video name**

than comes underscore _

and than

**fe5eb9bf1= This is unique video ID**

than lastly

**.html = this is extension**

What i want to do is 
I want to remove any slashes, hyphens, dots and replace them with spaces and lastly i want to completely remove _fe5eb9bf1.html this type of porting from my urls
any idea ?

SO at the end i will get the result like this

```
videos of stars and stellites etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pathname.replace(/_[^.]+.[a-z]+$/, '').replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,' ');
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bPVbk/

Answer (score 0):

Easiest approach is just to use the **split** method. Something like

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
var videoname = pathname.split("_")[0];
videoname = videoname.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,' ');
```